# Page inheritance with a master page

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, webforms, master-pages

I have an aspx page with code behind, with a master page.
Furthermore this page extends a base class. The structure is the following:

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Specialized.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Specialized" %>
```

And this is the code behind

```
public partial class Specialized : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Page_Load` event of this page is never executed, while the `Page_Load` event of the base class is executed.

I can't understand why? Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: I looks _very_ strange to me that you call the virtual base `OnLoad`in an event handler (`Page_Load`). In my opinion this might lead to infinite recursion or, if the runtime is able to detect this, in some other behaviour.

Comment: Do _not_ write the line `base.OnLoad(e)`.

Comment: In addition, if you are new, do also _not_ learn [ASP.NET Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webforms/info), but learn [ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info) instead.

Comment: But anyway, the strange thing is that the Page_load code of the base page is executed, while the Page_load code of the specialized page is not, so that code is never reached